# Magento 1.9 strange links in layerer navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, google-analytics, link

I am having this problem in my magento site.
Sometimes in layered navigation when I hit a link of a category or filter I get the right link but in the end I get this:

```
?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIxJfLq9zm2QIVqArTCh34hwpwEAMYAyAAEgIR8fD_BwE
```

I have this only is some links and not all the time. Sometimes it just disappears. I check and found that it has something to do with google.
I have enabled auto tagging in my adwords account.
Also if you hit the link without this at the end it still works fine.
Can anyone help me? What is this thing and why I see it?

Answer (score 0):

> Gclid is a globally unique tracking parameter (Google Click
>   Identifier) used by Google to pass information back and forth between
>   Google AdWords and Google Analytics. If you enable URL auto tagging in
>   Google AdWords, Google will append a unique ?gclid parameter on your
>   destination URLs at run-time.

Basically google is adding identifier so it can track where user came from.

You should not see it if you came to your website directly. (not from google adwords)

And you should see it if you landed on your site through adwords.

Comment: I never came to my site from adwords...I assume you mean from an advertisement. I only go directly to site. So as I can understand it's not something I should care off....It isn't an error or something in magento?